# alternative HttpClientHandler for Linux/Unix

Tags: c#, linux, unix, mono, dotnet-httpclient

I am looking for a portable drop in replacement for Mono HttpClient stack. The portable Mono version [part of the regular Mono stack] has bugs. I have been trying to fix one specific bug affecting our project. Due to highly asynchronous nature of the library necessary for async operations, lack of documentation and comments in the Mono code, it is taking a long time.
I see that Microsoft does not bother implementing Http stack in C#, instead using reliable libraries - WinHttp and libcurl. Unfortunately, porting libcurl to Mono is also a job.
Legally, HttpClient allows replacing a handler, creating an alternative stack. There is a CFNetwork handler for iOS and ModernHttpClient for iOS/Android and other platforms. Yet, ModernHttpClient does not work, for me, as a drop-in replacement either.
Any suggestions? My code as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var threadCancelationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var sl = new StatusLoop();
        sl.HttpClientTimeout = int.Parse(args[0]);
        sl.StatusFreq = int.Parse(args[1]);

       Task.Run(async () => await sl.RunStatusLoop(threadCancelationToken.Token), threadCancelationToken.Token);
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class StatusLoop
{
    public int HttpClientTimeout;
    public int StatusFreq;

    public async Task RunStatusLoop(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
//       var handler = new HttpClientHandler
         var handler = new NativeMessageHandler
         {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"),
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseProxy = false
         };

//       var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler())
         var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
         {
             Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.HttpClientTimeout)
         };

         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

         ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://192.168.1.22/api/v1/system/status/", cancellationToken);
                if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    Console.Write(".");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("HttpClientGetStatus - exception\n\r" + ex.ToString());
            }

            Thread.Sleep(this.StatusFreq * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have used an alternative HttpClientHandler on Linux/Mac, please share your experience.

Thank you

Comment: What actually is the bug?

Comment: Bug in Mono? Incorrect http keep-alive implementation. Why?

Comment: what version of mono is the one you're using?

Answer (score 0):

There is source for one [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.Unix.cs) but I don't know if the [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/4.0.0-beta-23516) contains this Unix code yet

Comment: Thank you for noticing my question. Your link is Microsoft Open Source .NET, which I mentioned in the question. I am sure that MSFT folks know their job. Open Source .NET is still flaky and not every snapshot/module builds. Yet, http stack builds fine. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with Mono. I ended-up fixing a bug in Mono/C# stack. I am not a guru of any kind. At least for us the fix works. Mono folks made the contribution process easy, but it takes time. For now, the PR has been open for a week. Hoping someone will merge it, or perhaps improve the fix, by themselves or with me, then merge.

Comment: saw that you are perhaps with MSFT. Your engineers are great. I, from personal experience, disagree with some folks about Open Source .NET RC1 being production ready. This in no way means that I criticize the team or the effort, in any way. They are doing an amazing job etc. IMHO, Open Source .NET just needs more time. Code quality is NOT the reason I did not take Microsoft libcurl based http stack. It just turned out easier, for me, to fix a bug a Mono.